# tkinter stacked frames - frame 2 needs to reflect what was chosen in frame 1

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I am creating a GUI for a stats report generator script and am having trouble getting tkinter to do what I want. Below is the complete code. Bascically, there is an App that controls two stacked frames (Pages). The first page is where you enter some basics that you want in the reports, such as product, year, quarter and region. I want the region that is chosen on the first page to dictate which country checkboxes appear on the second page. There is a function called country_lists() that takes in the region and returns the countries for that region. selected_region is the global variable that contains the region chosen on page 1.

The problem is, page2 is initiated before selected_region is chosen on page1 so I am having trouble getting the correct countries to appear on page 2.

Right now I have to start with assigning a region manually in order for the script to run. For example:
    selected_region = 'APAC'

Then once the script is running, I comment this out and the script sort of works by using selected_region, but it uses the selected_region from the previous time I ran the script (using the previous global value). I want page2 to display checkboxes for countries in the newly selected region.

I have played with moving the page 2 init into the multCommands function in initUI, but it only yielded a blank second page. For example:

```
if selected_product == "All":
    self.initPage2(page)
    self.callback()
else:
    try:
        self.close_window()
    except:
        pass
```

I am still new to tkinter so I find it hard to understand what I need to do to make this work. Any help is appreciated!

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog

productList = ['All', 'VV', 'NG', 'Traffic', 'Hypothetical']
regionList = ['APAC', 'AU', 'NA', 'SAM', 'India', 'EEU', 'WEU', 'MEA', 'TWN', 'ROW']
quarterList = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']
yearList = ['2013', '2014', '2015', '2016']
selected_country_list = []

EEU_country_codes = { 'Czech Republic':'C0', 'Greece':'GR', 'Hungary':'H1',  'Poland':'P0', 'Russia':'R0', 'Slovakia':'M2', 'Turkey':'T0', 'Ukraine':'U0'}
MEA_country_codes = { 'Bahrain':'WG', 'Israel':'IS', 'Jordan':'JO', 'Kuwait':'WD',    'Lebanon':'LB','Oman':'WF', 'Qatar':'WC', 'Saudi Arabia':'WH', 'South Africa':'L0', 'UAE':'WE'}
WEU_country_codes = { 'Austria':'A1', 'Andorra':'ZG', 'Belgium':'BB', 'Denmark':'S4', 'Finland':'FI', 'France':'F0', 'Germany':'G0', 'Ireland':'EB', 'Italy':'I0', 'Liechtenstein':'ZL', 'Luxembourg':'LU', 'Malta':'M9','Monaco':'MC', 'Netherlands':'N3', 'Norway':'N1',  'Portugal':'KA', 'San Marino':'MZ','Spain':'KE','Sweden':'S0','Switzerland':'CA', 'United Kingdom':'ED', 'Vatican City':'VS', 'Gibraltar':'K2'}
SAM_country_codes = { 'Brazil':'SB', 'Argentina':'W3', 'Chile':'C6', 'Colombia':'CB', 'Costa Rica':'CR', 'Panama':'PB', 'Peru':'PE', 'Uruguay':'UY'}
NA_country_codes = { 'United States':'US', 'Mexico':'MX', 'Canada':'DB', 'Puerto Rico':'94', 'US Virgin Islands':'94' }
APAC_country_codes = { 'Indonesia':'UF', 'Malaysia':'W2', 'Singapore':'W1', 'Thailand':'JN'}
TWN_country_codes = { 'Taiwan':'VD'}
India_country_codes = { 'India':'5R'}
AU_country_codes = { 'Australia':'AU', 'New Zealand':'NZ'}
ROW_country_codes = {}
ROW_country_codes.update(APAC_country_codes)
ROW_country_codes.update(AU_country_codes)
ROW_country_codes.update(India_country_codes)
ROW_country_codes.update(TWN_country_codes)
region_country_hash = { 'SAM': SAM_country_codes, 'NA': NA_country_codes, 'APAC': APAC_country_codes, 'India': India_country_codes,'AU': AU_country_codes, 'ROW': ROW_country_codes, 'EEU': EEU_country_codes, 'WEU': WEU_country_codes, 'MEA': MEA_country_codes, 'EU': EU_country_codes, 'TWN': TWN_country_codes}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
def country_lists(region):

    use_hash = region_country_hash[region]
    # convert to an array
    region_country_list = []
    for k, v in sorted(use_hash.iteritems()):
        region_country_list.append(k)

    if len(region_country_list) > 1:
        region_country_list.append('All')

    current_country_list = region_country_list[0:8]
    current_country_list1 = region_country_list[8:16]
    current_country_list2 = region_country_list[16:24]

    return current_country_list, current_country_list1, current_country_list2

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Page(Frame):                                                               
    def __init__(self, parent, page, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, borderwidth=0, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.centerWindow()

        if page == "p1":
            self.initUI(page)
        else:
            self.initPage2(page)

    def initUI(self, page):

        root.title("Stats Aggregator")

        windowBorder = LabelFrame(self, text=" Choose data to compare: ", padx=0, pady=0, width=740,height=260)
        windowBorder.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady=10, padx=10, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 4, sticky='NW')

        region = StringVar()
        qtr = StringVar()
        month = StringVar()
        year = StringVar()
        product = StringVar()
        version = StringVar()

        select_width = 48

        product.set('Select Product:') # default value
        S = OptionMenu(self,  product, *productList)
        S.config(width=select_width)
        S.pack( side = LEFT)
        S.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='NW')

        region.set('Select Region:') # default value
        O = OptionMenu(self, region, *regionList)
        O.config(width=select_width)
        O.pack( side = LEFT)
        O.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='NW')

        qtr.set('Select Quarter:') # default value
        P = OptionMenu(self, qtr, *quarterList)
        P.config(width=select_width)
        P.pack( side = LEFT)
        P.grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='NW')

        year.set('Select Year:') # default value
        R = OptionMenu(self,  year, *yearList)
        R.config(width=select_width)
        R.pack( side = LEFT)
        R.grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='NW')

        submitButton = LabelFrame(self, text="", padx=0, pady=0, width=740,height=80)
        submitButton.grid(row = 4, column = 0, pady=10, padx=10, columnspan = 2, sticky='NW')

        Button(self, text = '     Submit     ', command = lambda: multCommands(region, qtr, product, year)).grid(row = 4, columnspan = 2, pady=35, padx=15, sticky='N')

        def multCommands(region, qtr, product, year):

            global selected_region
            global selected_qtr
            global selected_product
            global selected_year
            global selected_country_list

            region = str(region.get())
            qtr = str(qtr.get())
            year = str(year.get())
            product = str(product.get())

            selected_region = region
            selected_qtr = qtr
            selected_product = product
            selected_year = year

            printInputs(selected_region, selected_qtr, selected_product, selected_year)


            # This is the logic that determines whether or not to go on to a second
            # page of inputs. A second page of inputs will appear (asking for version (placeholder))
            # if the product selected is "All". Otherwise, the root window will close after one page of inputs.
            # -------------------------------
            if selected_product == "All":
                self.callback()
            else:
                try:
                    self.close_window()
                except:
                    pass
            # -------------------------------

        def printInputs(region, qtr, product, year):

            print "The selected region is:", selected_region
            print "The selected quarter is:", selected_qtr
            print "The selected year is:", selected_year
            print "The selected product is:", selected_product


    def initPage2(self, page):

        # selected_region = 'APAC'
        # print "The selected region is:", selected_region
        # returns a list of tuple containing three lists no longer than 8 elements each
        country_list_tuple = country_lists(selected_region)
        current_country_list = country_list_tuple[0]
        current_country_list1 = country_list_tuple[1]
        current_country_list2 = country_list_tuple[2]

        list_len = len(current_country_list)

        windowBorder = LabelFrame(self, text=" Choose countries to include: ", padx=0, pady=20, width=740,height=260, borderwidth=0)
        windowBorder.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady=10, padx=10, columnspan = 3, rowspan = list_len+1, sticky='W')

        global selected_country_list
        country_list0 = []
        country_list1 = []
        country_list2 = []
        #----------------------------
        def chkbox_checked(arg1, arg2, arg3):
            global selected_country_list
            consolidated_country_list = []
            cb = arg1
            cb_v = arg2
            if arg3 == 0:
                country_list = country_list0
            if arg3 == 1:
                country_list = country_list1
            if arg3 == 2:
                country_list = country_list2

            for ix, item in enumerate(cb):
                country_list[ix]=(cb_v[ix].get())

            for i in country_list0:
                consolidated_country_list.append(i)
            for i in country_list1:
                consolidated_country_list.append(i)
            for i in country_list2:
                consolidated_country_list.append(i)
            print "consolidated_country_list:", consolidated_country_list, len(consolidated_country_list)
            selected_country_list = consolidated_country_list

        #----------------------------
        checkbox_area0 = LabelFrame(windowBorder, text="", padx=0, pady=0, width=200,height=150, borderwidth=0)
        checkbox_area0.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady=0, padx=10, sticky='NW')

        bb = []
        bb_v = []
        for ix, text in enumerate(current_country_list):
            bb_v.append(StringVar())
            off_value=''
            bb.append(Checkbutton(checkbox_area0, text=text, onvalue=text, offvalue=off_value, variable=bb_v[ix], command= lambda: chkbox_checked(bb, bb_v, 0)))
            bb[ix].grid(row=ix, column=0, padx=50, sticky='W')
            country_list0.append(off_value)
            bb[-1].deselect()

        checkbox_area1 = LabelFrame(windowBorder, text="", padx=0, pady=0, width=200,height=150, borderwidth=0)
        checkbox_area1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady=0, padx=10, sticky='NW')
        #column 1
        if current_country_list1:
            cb = []
            cb_v = []
            for ix, text in enumerate(current_country_list1):
                cb_v.append(StringVar())
                off_value=''
                cb.append(Checkbutton(checkbox_area1, text=text, onvalue=text, offvalue=off_value, variable=cb_v[ix], command= lambda: chkbox_checked(cb, cb_v, 1)))
                cb[ix].grid(row=ix, column=0, padx=50, sticky='W')
                country_list1.append(off_value)
                cb[-1].deselect()

        checkbox_area2 = LabelFrame(windowBorder, text="", padx=0, pady=0, width=200,height=150, borderwidth=0)
        checkbox_area2.grid(row = 1, column = 2, pady=0, padx=10, sticky='NW')
        #column 2
        if current_country_list2:
            db = []
            db_v = []
            for ix, text in enumerate(current_country_list2):
                db_v.append(StringVar())
                off_value=''
                db.append(Checkbutton(checkbox_area2, text=text, onvalue=text, offvalue=off_value, variable=db_v[ix], command= lambda: chkbox_checked(db, db_v, 2)))
                db[ix].grid(row=ix, column=0, padx=50, sticky='W')
                country_list2.append(off_value)
                db[-1].deselect()

        submitButton = LabelFrame(self, text="", padx=0, pady=0, width=740,height=80, borderwidth=0)
        submitButton.grid(row = list_len+1, column = 0, pady=10, padx=10, columnspan = 3, sticky='NW')

        Button(self, text = '     Generate Reports     ', command = lambda: multCommands2(selected_country_list)).grid(row = list_len+1, columnspan = 3, pady=35, padx=15, sticky='N')

        def multCommands2(selected_country_list):
            self.callback()
            printInputs2(selected_country_list)

        def printInputs2(selected_country_list):
            print "The selected countries are:", selected_country_list, len(selected_country_list)

    def centerWindow(self):
        w = 760
        h = 380

        sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = root.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2
        root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h, x, y))

    def onlift(self):
        self.lift()

    def close_window(self):
        root.destroy()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
class App(Frame):                                               
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.handler)

        p1 = Page(self, 'p1')                                   
        p2 = Page(self, 'p2')

        p1.callback = p2.onlift                                
        p2.callback = p2.close_window                           

        p1.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)             
        p2.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)             

        p1.onlift()

    def handler(self):
        if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit?", "Are you sure you want to quit?"):
            root.destroy()
            print "Destoy root window."
            self.master.quit()
            print "Quit main loop."
            sys.exit()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program structure is quite skewed. The whole point of having a class object is that all instances of that class should be similar. Therefore, if you do choose to use classes for each page, they should be separate classes.

A better methods would be the following:

```
Class App
    def initPage1(self):
        #Do all of page1 stuff here
    def initPage2(self):
        #Do all of page2 stuff here
```

OR
    Class Page1
    Class Page2
    Class App
        def initPages(self):
            p1 = Page1()
            p2 = Page2()

As for updating the pages, when the value is updated in page1 it should call a handler. This handler could call something like self.master.p2.update(updated_value) or it could call self.master.update(updated_value), in which case the update function in App would call an update function in p2.

Comment: This is theoretically helpful, but I can't picture how it would all be put together.. I think I would need to see specific examples that I can test.

Comment: I tried doing what you described.. I got rid of the App class and initialized both pages from within the page class, but I couldn't get it to work. Can you show me how to initialize 2 frames and use update/onlift to allow the second page to be updated based on what was chosen in the first page? Also how to create and use the handler?